# how to show value on button of toolbar in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem, uibuttonbaritem

I am doing project of bill. there are many bills that i can scroll and each bill have many items with quantity and price. At the button, there are also many buttons on toolbar. Total Price of bill is 1 button among them, and i don't know how to show the number of total price on this button !

Answer (score 0):

A UIButton has a currentTitle-property and you should be able to get the title from that.

A UIBarButtonItem has a possibleTitles-property which is an NSSet containing all possible titles the bar button might have. If it is simply one then you might retrieve this title by the following function:

```
NSString *buttontitle = [myBarButtonItem.possibleTitles anyObject];
```

if it contains more then first transform it to an array and then retrieve the title you need:

```
NSArray *titlesArray = [myBarButtonItem.possibleTitles allObjects];
```

if you know what title it might contain you might want to use this:

```
Bool *expectedTitleFound = [myBarButtonItem.possibleTitles contains:@"MyTitle"];
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.