# getting the current title of a UIBarButtonItem IBAction sender

Tags: ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

The following code snippet works fine for a `UIButton`.

```
- (IBAction)start: (UIButton *)sender{
NSString *buttonTitle = sender.currentTitle;
if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString: @"Start Record"]) {..}
```

But I am now wanting to make the button a `UIBarButtonItem`, instead, and they have no such property as `currentTitle`.

[This answer explains that possibleTitles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983340/) is an array of properties for `UIBarButtonItem`s but I cannot understand how to access that array from a `sender`. I have tried constructs like the following because the button title of interest it the third one in the button bar, but am running afoul of the proper use of array items.

```
NSString *buttonTitle = sender.possibleTitles[2];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you the title of a **UIBarButtonItem** when it is touched

```
- (IBAction)barButton_touched:(id)sender
{
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

    NSString *title = barButtonItem.title;
    NSLog(@"Button Title %@",title);
}
```